Can not access data from Shopify Graphql API in Node.JS
const foilQuery = `query{
            products(first: 1, query: "(title:${match.name})AND(title:${match.number})AND(title:foil)") {
                edges {
                    node {
                        totalInventory
                    }
                }
            }
        }`;
        const nonFoilQuery = `query{
            products(first: 1, query: "(title:${match.name})AND(title:${match.number})AND NOT (title:foil)") {
                edges {
                    node {
                        totalInventory
                    }
                }
            }
        }`;

        const [foilResponse, nonFoilResponse] = await Promise.all([
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
                data: { query: foilQuery },
                headers: {
                    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': process.env.SHOPIFY_TOKEN,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }),
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT,
                data: { query: nonFoilQuery },
                headers: {
                    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': process.env.SHOPIFY_TOKEN,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            })
        ]);

When looking at the response for a successful query, I see
{
  data: { products: { edges: [Array] } },
  extensions: {
    cost: {
      requestedQueryCost: 3,
      actualQueryCost: 3,
      throttleStatus: [Object]
    }
  }
}

And I am unable to access any of the data in the array, and nonFoilResponse.data.products always shows as undefined. I would like to be able to access this data and map both the foil and non-foil to later be rendered by a partial.
